# No OpenGL on amd64 chroot on Arch Linux ARM

Tags: arch-linux, qemu, chroot, opengl

I am on Arch Linux ARM, and am running a 64-bit chroot in order to get access to some things that are only x86_64. However, when trying to start yuzu or dolphin-emu, it starts, but the text is not there, and it has this error message:

```
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: virtio_gpu
libGL error: failed to get magic
libGL error: failed to load driver: virtio_gpu
```

All the proper drivers are installed, and OpenGL works with no errors on host.

EDIT: It seems that for some reason, llvmpipe is being used on the chroot instead of virgl. It seems the chroot isn't aware that it is in a VM, so it can't access all of the VM-specific things.

EDIT 2: After a bit of testing, I've narrowed it down to the fact the QEMU's user emulation blocks programs from seeing the GPU.